# C# EPPLUS excel array formula workarounds

Tags: c#, .net, interop, epplus

The current version of `EPPLUS` support the creation of excel formulas but NOT excel array formulas, despite having the `CreateFormulaArray()` method.

When using the `CreateFormulaArray()` method, the correct formula string will appear on the excel formula editor. However, the formula does not actually execute on the sheet.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any *clever* workaround to this without having to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop`

My code is:

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary");
    pck.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToStart("Summary");
    var summaryWS = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    summaryWS.Cells["C2"].Value = 2;
    summaryWS.Cells["C3"].Value = 3;
    summaryWS.Cells["C4"].Value = 8;

    summaryWS.Cells["A1"].CreateArrayFormula("STDEV.P($C$2:$C$4)*SQRT(8*260)");
}
```

my output in excel would be `#NAME?`
The formula editor would show `{=STDEV.P($C$2:$C$4)*SQRT(8*260)}`

Comment: Works fine for me using EPPlus version 4.0.4.  Post your code to others can take a look.

Comment: I posted my code. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems Excel is misinterpreting the function name `STDEV.P` which is the newer version of `STDEVP`.  If you look at the XML output AFTER opening and saving with excel the wb EPPlus generates you will see it says `_xludf.STDEV.P` which means it thinks it is user-defined.

You can do one of two things.  You could use the old version of the function:

```
summaryWS.Cells["A1"].CreateArrayFormula("STDEVP($C$2:$C$4)*SQRT(8*260)");
```

which is probably less then ideal since you always want to stick with the latest version.  In that case, force excel to recognize the function like this:

```
summaryWS.Cells["A1"].CreateArrayFormula("_xlfn.STDEV.P($C$2:$C$4)*SQRT(8*260)");
```

Comment: The xlfn. also works with the StdDev functions outside of arrays, too. Ran into the same issue, where it wasn't recognizing the STDEV.S function, but appending the xlfn tag fixed it. *ws.Cells(col & thisRow).Formula = "_xlfn.STDEV.S(" & col & firstRow & ":" & col & lastRow & ")"*

Comment: Awesome work....this saved me big time. I was trying to get the FILTER function working and I just needed the "_xlfn." previx